# Select some properties of an array of object and rename it

Tags: powershell

I have an array of objects, which have the property of `p1, p2, p3, p4`.

```
$objectArray = [PSCustomObject]@{
    p1 = "Value1"; p2 = "Value2"; p3 = "Value3"; p4 = "Value4"
},[PSCustomObject]@{
    p1 = "Value5"; p2 = "Value6"; p3 = "Value7"; p4 = "Value8"
}
```

And I have a property-name-mapping hashtable, for example

```
$propertyReplacements = @{
    "p1" = "x1"
    "p2" = "y1"
}
```

How to select only the properties which exist in the keys of hash table `$propertyReplacements`; and rename the property name to the values in the hash table?

The result will be

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    x1 = "Value1"; y1 = "Value2";
},[PSCustomObject]@{
    x1 = "Value5"; y1 = "Value6";
}
```

---

The properties filtering can be

```
$objectArray | select -Property @($propertyReplacements.Keys) |
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses an [ordered dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#creating-ordered-dictionaries) and casting [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3#converting-a-hashtable) to create new objects, I really don't think [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) is the proper tool for this.

```
# use a temporary ordered dictionary
$tmp = [ordered]@{}
# enumerate each object
foreach($obj in $objectArray) {
    # store the PSMemberInfoIntegratingCollection for later access
    $properties = $obj.PSObject.Properties
    # enumerate the hash keys
    foreach($key in $propertyReplacements.Keys) {
        # if the hash key exists as property Name in this object
        if($prop = $properties.Item($key)) {
            # create a new property Name using the Value of the hashtable
            # and keep the current Value of the value
            $tmp[$propertyReplacements[$prop.Name]] = $prop.Value
        }
    }
    # create a new object casting this type accelerator
    [pscustomobject] $tmp
    # and clear the dictionary for the next object
    $tmp.Clear()
}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions. However, they change the values instead of property names.

Comment: @ca9163d9 that was my bad, I'm sorry. I thought you were looking to update the values instead of the property names (didnt read properly your expected output). This update should work

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. BTW, I also found a solution and posted as another answer. How does it compare with the temp obj solution in your answer?

Comment: @ca9163d9 that code is not working for me but the ideal would be to not use `Select-Object` in this case. It performs much slower than using an ordered dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
foreach($k in $propertyReplacements.Keys) {
    if ($k -ne $propertyReplacements.$k) {
        $objectArray = $objectArray | select *,{n=$propertyReplacements.$k; $e={$_.$k}}
        $objectArray = $objectArray | select -ExcludeProperty $k
    }
}
# $objectArray has updated property names now
```